# configuring mongodb-cross store in spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-mongo

is there anyway to configure **spring-data-mongodb-cross-store** with **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** without using xml ?

in my JPA entity i have

```
@RelatedDocument
private Image image;
```

and here's my Image class (Document)

```
@Document
public class CartoonImages implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 2297669065273705668L;

@Id
private ObjectId id;

private String filesize;

private String filetype;

private String filename;

private String base64;

...
```

when i try to insert an image to my entity, ***com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'image'*** exception is fired

since am using **@SpringBootApplication** , what can i do to configure the cross-store? :)

thanks in advance